# Can I migrate to database created without migration in Entity framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, sql-server-ce, entity-framework-migrations

I had created a *desktop application* which uses **SQL CE 4.0** and **Entity** **framework** with **Code First** mode. So, Initially I had installed application on a system, it worked fine.

Now I added few properties to model class, so for this purpose I enabled migrations using `Enable-Migrations` and added new migration using `Add-Migration "MyMigration"`. This was also successfull and I was able to install new version and upgrade database without any issue.

But now when I install this setup on a system with no existing database then it fails, so after studying I realized that I need to add **Initial Migration** So, I revoked changes in model and also deleted my SQLCE database file, added initial migration, then `Update-Database`. So if I try to Update-Database using old-database which was created without enabling migrations then it fails, it tries to apply initial migration to database which it shouldn't according to me.

Now if I delete old-database file and then Update-Database then new db is created and then once again added my changes to model and added expected migration.

So after this, turnaround I am able to install my application on blank system but it fails on a system with old database i.e. it doesn't upgrade database.

It tries to apply Initial-Migration also, i.e. creating all the tables once again and fails saying that, *The table already exists* which isn't expected.

Comment: Try using the command update-database -verbose ... after failing scroll up and you'll see which table is causing the issue

Comment: Update-Database works but, when I build setup file and deploy on any of the client system, it tries to apply InitialCreate migration and recreate all tables, which gives error as **XYZ table already exists**

Answer (score 3):

The thing is that it checks a table called Migrations, where *I think it get information of the current squema and changes*. If you make a lof of changes of the DB without using EF, somehow you'll get to a point when a lot of clonflicts would happen.

You can use [fluent migrations](https://github.com/fluentmigrator/fluentmigrator) to do everything yourself and have more control of the changes and the rollbacks

Example:

```
 [Migration(201610250659)]
public class _201610250659_AddedMinimumValue_Prices : Migration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        Alter.Table("Prices")
            .AddColumn("MinimunValue").AsInt32().NotNullable().WithDefaultValue(1);
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        Delete.Column("MinimunValue")
            .FromTable("Prices");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is

```
update-database
```

this will update the database accordingly. Just remember everytime you add-migration you need to update-database, and when you install the system somewhere else, all you need is to do a update-database to get the older database on par with entity framework.

Comment: I am deploying my application through msi installer created with help of InstallShield, how can I update-database in that case?

Comment: I've never installed in with msi installer before, but anyhow, entity framewok shouldnt try initial-migration everytime, it should only do it once. you do add-migration -> update-database and the database should have the migrationhistory table to update properly, atleast that is the way entity framework should work

Comment: Please go through my question once again, hope you understand my problem. I am installing my setup on 100 different machines.

Comment: Yes how are you doing add-migration? You said you added new migration using add-migration so you are definitely typing this somewhere right? why can't you run update-database after add-migration?

Comment: Does your database have a migrations table? When you install from scratch using update-database, how many rows are in migrations table? You should get one row for each add-migration you've done. Now i suspect old database doesnt upgrade because they have different rows in migrations table, for example, new database could have something like init, first-update etc, but your old database could have initial as the first row which is different from your application and it fails. I suggest you do a clean database install on each machine using update-database only, don't do any initial-database.

Comment: Its really hard to tell because it could be anything

Comment: And when you update your model and add-migration, just update-database on new machines see it works fine now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138197/discussion-between-aniket-bhansali-and-mindless).

Answer (score 1):

you need to check if into initial scripts, if table already exist or not. Its not EF issue, even if your try to simply run create database scripts with table definition without checking existing one, it will fail.

For Example,

I don't have any database installed into my machine and I'm having script for create new with some table into it..

so this is script for creating table

```
    USE [TestStudent]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[EmployeeInformation]    Script Date: 18-03-2017 19:12:40 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EmployeeInformation](
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [LastName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Designation] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_EmployeeInformation] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[sample]    Script Date: 18-03-2017 19:12:41 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[sample](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TableId] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_sample] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Notice that I'm just creating the tables not checking for object existence, now if I run this on new machine with blank database it will run without error..

[image]

Now, I try to run same script on existing database with existing objects may be for updating some tables like in your case but here's the trick, your update script will be at the bottom of this... so it will first try to create the tables and if existed it will throw you error..

[image]

so you need to check the object existence before you create tables, like in this script...

```
    USE [TestStudent]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[EmployeeInformation]    Script Date: 18-03-2017 19:22:16 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[EmployeeInformation]') AND type in (N'U'))
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EmployeeInformation](
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [LastName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Designation] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_EmployeeInformation] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
END
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[sample]    Script Date: 18-03-2017 19:22:16 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[sample]') AND type in (N'U'))
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[sample](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TableId] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_sample] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
END
GO
```

so when you try to run this, it will skip the already existing objects that are in table will proceed to your update scripts...

[image]

hope this helps...

Answer (score 1):

OK, so if you have, say, 2 migrations: Initial and MyMigration and now you have an old database that has the changes represented by the first migration, but not the second and it keeps trying to apply the unneeded first migration - then you can resolve it this way:

1) Generate a complete migration script (BTW, this can be used to create a blank database of your model):

```
Update-Database -Script -SourceMigration: $InitialDatabase
```

2) The code at the top of this script will check for the existance of __MigrationHistory and create it if it is missing.

3A) Next, it will check for each migration with code like below. Since your database already has these you should comment those lines out.

```
IF @CurrentMigration < '201702231958592_Initial'
BEGIN
     -- objects already exist, but EF doesn't know this
     -- CREATE TABLE, etc.
END
```

3B) Entity framework will insert a record into __MigrationHistory so it knows this migration has been applied. Do not comment this line out! (The long hex string is a representation of your model).

```
INSERT [dbo].[__MigrationHistory]([MigrationId], [ContextKey], [Model], [ProductVersion])
VALUES (N'201702231958592_Initial', N'MyApp.Data.Migrations.Configuration',  0x1F8B08000000
```

4) Steps 3A and 3B will be repeated for each migration, so leave them in there if they have not been applied. Comment out the object changes if they do.

Moving forward if you haven't messed with migrations EF will be smart enough to apply the changes to various deployments in different states of applied migrations.

As to your installer issue, you could either call this script via ADO.NET or you could use [DbMigrator](https://romiller.com/2012/02/09/running-scripting-migrations-from-code/) to do migrations in code.